# json object with function and array as values

Tags: arrays, json

Hi I hava a json structure as specified below with an array and a function as values for keys specified below, however i am seeing errors when i validate this json , please let me know what is wrong

```
var cars = {
   "config": [{'id': 'hc_3',
               'title': 'Show Details'
   }],
   "handler": function(id) {
    if(id == 'hc_3') {
        console.log('test')
    }
   }
};
```

Comment: Errors?  I see no errors.  You shouldn't fib, it's naughty.  If you're not naughty, [edit] and add in these errors and how you're getting them.

Comment: Unable to format the JSON input. Found starting '{' but missing '}' at the end. at character 0 near 'null'

Comment: I am using http://www.freeformatter.com/json-formatter.html